# Combinations: What is the number of facial expressions possible with 5 eyebrows, 11 mouth shapes, 13 signs, 16 different eyeshapes, & 5 eyeball pairs?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am making a 3D model with quite a few number of shapekeys: including a way to account `5` different positions for each of the eyebrows left and right, morphing `11` different mouth shapes, able to express `13` different signs that can pop up on top of the avatar's head, `16` different shapes for eyes with a right wink, left wink, and both wink variations for all 16 of them, and  `5` different sets of eyeballs where the user gets to make their own textures and use them.

Now, here's a question:

*What is the maximum number of unique facial expressions possible for this avatar?*

I believe this is a *Combination* question with these numbers here (5, 11, 13...) but I have no idea how to calculate for the eyes! Here are some of the details that's throwing me off:

More than one *signs* can pop up on the avatar's head. So, for example,  and ✨ and ❗ and ❓ can be all used without any particular order. My guess here is <strike>`13!`</strike>(This is for permutations therefore incorrect.)

For the eyeshapes, if I have a ＞-shaped eye on the Right and a ♥-filled eye on the Left, I would like to say it's a different facial expression from a ♥-filled eye on the Right and a ＜-shaped eye on the Left. Therefore, `♥♥`, `＞＜`, `＞♥`, and `♥＜` are considered to be 4 unique eyeshape combinations I may derive from the given sets(♥♥ and ><). Now, I have 16 different eyeshapes and I do not know how many unique combinations are possible.

For the mouths, there can only be one mouth used at any given facial expression, so I believe this is a simple `×11` here.

For the eyebrows, I have 5 different eyebrow positions with a different shapekey assigned for left and right as well, somewhat a similar setup to the eyeshapes.
Like the eyeshapes, I would like to consider that eyebrows that look like `／／`, `＼＼`, `＼／`, and `／＼` are all different. Once again, I have no idea how to express this in numbers...

For the eyeball pairs, I had created 5 different pairs of eyeballs where the user may use them in any combinations. So, let's say that a user had created eyes with  drawn in. They may use the Left eye of the avatar as their custom-defined  eye while using ♥ eye on the right. I would like to consider this facial expression to be different from having  eye on the right and ♥ eye on the left.

I was thinking about this problem for several days now but I could not think of any solutions to it. If anyone would like to share anything regarding one could go on about how to calculate problems like this, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: I belive you're just looking for the product of these numbers,
$$
5 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 16 \cdot 5
$$
Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

Comment: I am by no means a mathematician, however, I have a feeling that the solution may be slightly more evolved than the answer provided here.

Comment: You've been provided with a reference too.

Comment: So basically, I've spent the past few days trying to figure out a dumbfoundedly simple multiplication problem...?

Comment: Yes...  Note that factorials are *also* a "*simple multiplication problem*"... $5!$ being the number of ways to arrange five objects following the steps "Pick the first" (5 options), "Pick the second" (4 remaining options), "Pick the third" (3 remaining options) etc... for $5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$

Comment: Now... it is not perfectly clear how you have organized your numbers and these "eyeball pairs" for instance... If in your count of $5$ "pairs" you included $\$\heartsuit$ only once and did not include the other order of $\heartsuit\$$... then perhaps you want to adjust your count as each "pair" involving different symbols actually correspond to two different arrangements for the eyes instead of only one like the $\$\$$ where both symbols are the same.  It may have been easier to have described this as "picking the left eye" followed by "picking the right eye" assuming that all are valid

Comment: It is also not perfectly clear how you distinguish between your *eye shapes* and *eyeball pairs*... whether a "closed eye" with one particular eyeball is "different" than a closed eye with a different particular eyeball... The easiest interpretation is certainly what Matti used above.  The problem gets as simple or complicated as one likes though and in the end it is up to you.  It will still likely be some combination of Rule of Product and/or Rule of Sum.